# Selecting dataframe rows with "list" columns based on string conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with the following structure:

[image: dataframe]

I want to select from that dataframe only the rows that contain **all** of a given list of ingredients. For example, I want just the rows that contain "garlic","peas" and "onion".
A small issue is that I want to check not if there is an exact match in the ingredients list with "onion", but if there is an ingredient in that list that contains the substring "onion".

How would I write an elegant oneliner for this? I've found something like this online:

```
ing = ["onion","garlic","peas"]
mask = dataframe[column].apply(lambda x: any(item for item in ing if item in x))
rez = dataframe[mask]
```

But this I believe works with exact matches only (if the ingredient "onions" is in the column, it won't register as a match), and it returns the rows that contain any of the ingredients.

Comment: Just a few tips regarding good questions: don't put the code as an image, but rather copy it in (so we can copy into our notebooks and such). Also, try to supply minimum working example - example frame and list, such that you have both clear positive and clear negative match.

Answer (score 0):

Try if this works:

```
import pandas as pd
ing = [
    ['bla', 'blabla', ['apple', 'garlic']],
    ['bla2', 'blabla2', ['pear', 'bread']],
    ['bla3', 'blabla3', ['pear', 'garlic', 'bread']],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(ing, columns=['name', 'sthng', 'ingr'])
l = ['pear', 'bread']

df.loc[df['ingr'] == pd.Series([l]*len(df['ingr'])), :]
```

Using df.loc you can specify mask and what to return (: returns all columns). Comparison is a bit convoluted because pandas will try to match item-by-item, so in my case 3 rows with 2 elements, and will fail. And doing it without series it's trying to match one iterator (3 element) with a two dimensional iterator (that is `[['pear', 'bread'], ['pear', 'bread'], ['pear', 'bread']]`). Putting into series aligns it correctly for the comparison.

EDIT: I just noticed jezreal's answer. I have assumed you need to match only those that match the list of ingredients **exactly**. If you need to match **at least** the elements in the list, then his is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there, but you have to use nested statements:

```
mask = [all(any(ref in item for item in l) for ref in ing)
        for l in df['Ingredients']]

rez = df[mask]
```

Example output:

```
                           Ingredients
1  [garlic-powder, onion, peas, flour]
```

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Ingredients': [['garlic', 'onion', 'rice'],
                                   ['garlic-powder', 'onion', 'peas', 'flour']]})
```